# Difference between .results function and .result function in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was looking at the following code at https://github.com/JosephRobertBrown/HackReactorApplication/blob/master/TakeHomeProject/s.js

specifically this section,

```
Chat.fetch = function(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats?order=-createdAt",
        success: function(responseData){
            var messageList = [];
            var responseMessages = responseData.results;
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                messageList.push(responseMessages[i].text);
            };
            //Newest message is at index 0.  Reverse message list to add newest     messages to the bottom.
            callback(messageList.reverse());
        }
    });
};
```

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what this .results function does? I have already tried googling and even looked at the jQuery api documentation and can only find a .result function.

"event.result" = The last value returned by an event handler that was triggered by this event, unless the value was undefined.

Is this .result the same as .results?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`responseData.results` is not a function. `responseData` is an object that has a key `results`, which then also has a key `text` which is then being added to an array and sent to a callback function, in reverse.

Comment: Thanks! I got it, after reading your answer. I looked into PARSE REST's API Documentation and found it